# Pass parameter from cloudformation into a jenkins instance as a variable

Tags: jenkins, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to pass a parameter, which has been received by the user at the time of stack creation of a cloudformation template e.g. below

```
Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name of the environment
    AllowedPattern: "[a-z0-9-]+"
```

I'd like to pass that parameter into jenkins (which is being created as part of this stack), to be used as a global variable, probably using the [Global Variable String Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Global+Variable+String+Parameter+Plugin).

Is there a way of doing this purely using cloudformation? I've been told I will probably need something like Ansible or Terraform, but I would prefer to use only cloudformation if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in another CF script, there is an [export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html) option for the Outputs section that will export a variable.

```
Outputs:
  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name of the environment
    Export: !Sub EnvironmentName
    Value: EnvironmentName
```

Then you can interrogate from Jenkings or a sh script using [list-stack-resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/list-stack-resources.html) function.